# Multiple Float Images Throughout Text Article

Tags: html, css, image, css-float

Having problems with CSS, and I think what I want is possible without javascript, but I'm not sure.

I have an article of text that I want to display with 0-3 images(The number is dynamic for each article).  I want to display the 3 images all on the right-hand side of the page, with about 200-300px between them.  This much I have achieved just by floating the images, using clear, and margins.

The part I haven't been able to do is allow the text to flow between the images in that 200-300px worth of space.  I've tried relative positioning to push the images down to the part of the page I want them at, but the blank space reserved for them in the text by floating them stays where it is (i.e. the image ends up on top of text).

Is this even possible without js?  The text is also completely dynamic, so I can't use any element in the text as an anchor.

EDIT: Here's some code to explain a little:

The tags:

```
<div>
    <img class="floater" src="get_file.asp?image=1"/>
    <img class="floater" src="get_file.asp?image=2"/>
    <img class="floater" src="get_file.asp?image=3"/>
    <p>lots and lots of text and paragraphs go here....</p>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.floater
{
    float:right;
    height:250px;
    clear:both;
    margin-top:200px;//This creates space between the images, but the text doesn't flow between them
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve it only by using extra helper elements.

Look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kizu/BwySX/

You just add helper elements with zero width, so they are pushing your floaters with their height, but as they have zero width, the text flows near them almost perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that's possible. A margin always pushes everything to the sides.

I'd divide the text into paragraphs, and have only one image per paragraph. Then the image could float inside it.

Comment: Well, the text IS divided into paragraphs, but it is pre-generated, so I have no guarantee of there being any order to them.  Mingled with paragraphs are divs, <h> tags, etc. and I don't want to float on the right edge of a left-aligned header tag, so I can't just grab a generic element and float in it.  I thought about doing this for a while.